# Is it possible to use typeof with a generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is it possible to alias the return type of a generic function?  Like so?

```
export function ok<TValue>(value: TValue) {
  return {
    type: 'Ok',
    value,
  } as const;
}

export type Ok<TValue> = ReturnType<typeof ok<TValue>>;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun puzzle.  I believe the answer is (sort of) yes, but it's quite messy.

The fundamental issue is that `typeof ok` is going to consider `value` be `unknown`.  There's no good way to get a `type` declaration to rewrite `unknowns` so let's define some types to do that for us.

```js
// first, one that will visit all the properties in a type (recursively)
type ReplaceUnknownChildren<TIn, TWith> =
    { [K in keyof TIn]: ReplaceUnknown<TIn[K], TWith> };

// second, a type that replace any `unknown` with a specific type
type ReplaceUnknown<T, TWith> = unknown extends T ? TWith : T;
```

Then we want a variant of `ReturnType<T>` that will do this for us.  We have to explicit provide the `T` we want bound (the name needs to be in scope) so the syntax is a bit different from what you might expect.

```js
type GenericReturn<T, V> = 
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ?
        ReplaceUnknownChildren<R, V> :
        any;
```

Put it all together and

```js
type ReplaceUnknownChildren<TIn, TWith> =
    { [K in keyof TIn]: ReplaceUnknown<TIn[K], TWith> };

// second, a type that replace any `unknown` with a specific type
type ReplaceUnknown<T, TWith> = unknown extends T ? TWith : T;

type GenericReturn<T, V> = 
    T extends (...args: any[]) => infer R ?
        ReplaceUnknownChildren<R, V> :
        any;

export function ok<TValue>(value: TValue) {
  return {
    type: 'Ok',
    value,
  } as const;
}


export type Ok<TValue> = GenericReturn<typeof ok, TValue>;
```

Gives you this

[image: inferred type]

The big limitation is if you've got multiple generic types in the function's return type.  It's probably possible to do it with vararidic generic types (coming in TypeScript 4.0) but I'd have to play around with them to be sure.

Comment: I would have never figured that out.  I'm guessing if `ok` had more parameters, it wouldn't matter unless they are generic and part of the return?

Comment: Yeah, each type that is part of the return needs to be handled.  If they’re just parameters it shouldn’t matter.